# ASCII exchange using python with KEYENCE sensor

Tags: python-3.x

Please let me know.
It is a sensor made by KEYENCE and is supposed to exchange ASCII. The specification states that, as an example, if you send such data, it will be received normally.

SR, 06,101 CRLF (ASCII)
0x53, 0x52, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x36, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x30, 0x31, 0x00, 0x0A (hexadecimal)

I created this example with python code and sent it. However, although the signal is being transmitted, an alarm is displayed and it seems that it is not being received normally. I wrote ASCII code transmission in python for the first time this time. Is there something wrong with the code? Thank you for your cooperation.

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600)

senddata = [0x53, 0x52, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x31, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x30, 0x31, 0x0D, 0x0A]
send_binary = bytes(senddata)

ser.write(send_binary)
ser.close()
```

Comment: I use Raspberry Pi TX and RX.

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question with the little information provided.  Is this code running on the Pi or some other device?  How is the sensor connected to the device running code?  Which specific sensor made by KEYENCE are you attempting to connect with?

Comment: to itprorh66  
Thank you! The KEYENCE sensor is a sensor called "DL-RS1A". I am using "TXD" and "RXD" of "GPIO14" and "GPIO15" of Raspberry Pi.
I think that there is no problem with the wiring status, baud rate, bit length, parity.

Comment: When I run python, the alarm goes on for 2 seconds. The alarm lights up, so at least it seems that we are communicating.

Comment: According to the user manual when "The alarm indicator lights up before  communication starts." this is an indication that  "DL-RS1A is connected to a sensor amplifier that does not support DLRS1A"  Are you sure you have everything connected properly?

Comment: Also, per the User Manual thye default address for the sensor is 00 not 01 as indicated by your output data, so verify you have the correct address for the device.

Comment: If you don't already have it, I recommend you download the User Manual at [Keyence DL-RS1A User Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1556200/Keyence-Dl-Rs1a.html)

Comment: to itprorh66 Thank you!
There are two devices. The alarm will light for 2 seconds after running python.
There may be a problem with the hardware connection. Contact support and comment again.

Comment: Thank you very much. I put a monitor in serial communication and tried to monitor it. Then, a signal like noise was flowing in the hardware. That may have been an obstacle to this serial communication. Swap the hardware and comment again if successful.

Comment: To itprorh66. Thank you very much. I replaced the raspberry pie and it was solved. This code worked fine. I apologize to you for a fuss over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much. I replaced the raspberry pie and it was solved. This code worked fine. I apologize to you for a fuss over.